# Cannot get packageManagers or Context to pass to classes on functions that worked fine in main. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

> Listen I looked everywhere. Anything with remotely similiar keywords
> on SO and other sites I looked read tried and failed. Ive tried stuff
> written in java and Ive tried stuff slightly similiar. For some reason
> I am not able to get context to transfer to Classes from main
> activity. I read the android docs. I read the guides. The stuff works
> when its a function of onCreate on my mainactivity. Anywhere else.
> Nothing. Please help me. Im new to android studio but I programmed in
> C, and C++ in college. This is much more difficult to me to pick up. I
> just need some help

**Actual Error Full log at bottom
Running Mininum api 21 AVD at API 30. Java SDK 14.0.2**

```
2020-10-25 15:05:40.555 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.celadian.goodintents, PID: 12534
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:102)
            at com.celadian.goodintents.CreateTimer.startTimer(CreateTimer.kt:19)
            at com.celadian.goodintents.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:21)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.celadian.goodintents

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.home_button_one)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            println("Button Works")
            val newTimer = CreateTimer()
            newTimer.startTimer("Test", 3, this.applicationContext)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: MainActivity? = null

        fun applicationContext(): Context {
            return instance!!.applicationContext
        }

    }
}
```

**CreateTimer.kt**

```
package com.celadian.goodintents

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.AlarmClock


class CreateTimer: Application(){

fun startTimer(message: String, seconds: Int, context: Context) {

    val intent = Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER).apply {
        putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, seconds)
        putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true)
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}
'

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.celadian.goodintents">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GoodIntents">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_TIMER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.celadian.goodintents"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**LogCat**

> 2020-10-25 15:05:34.639 12534-12534/? I/ian.goodintent: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
> 2020-10-25 15:05:34.655 12534-12534/? I/ian.goodintent: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
> 2020-10-25 15:05:34.656 12534-12534/? W/ian.goodintent: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
> 2020-10-25 15:05:34.828 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.073 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.075 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.104 12534-12559/com.celadian.goodintents D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.105 12534-12559/com.celadian.goodintents D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.121 12534-12559/com.celadian.goodintents D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.673 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents W/ian.goodintent: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> 2020-10-25 15:05:35.674 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents W/ian.goodintent: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.061 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6145330, tid 12557
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.080 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.085 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.134 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd6145e20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.360 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd6145e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd5fc34b0) (first time)
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.402 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.407 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.408 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6145800, tid 12557
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.409 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.409 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f8d7f000 size 0x2000
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.435 12534-12557/com.celadian.goodintents D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
> 2020-10-25 15:05:36.609 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> 2020-10-25 15:05:40.551 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents I/System.out: Button Works
> 2020-10-25 15:05:40.552 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> 2020-10-25 15:05:40.555 12534-12534/com.celadian.goodintents E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.celadian.goodintents, PID: 12534
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:102)
> at com.celadian.goodintents.CreateTimer.startTimer(CreateTimer.kt:19)
> at com.celadian.goodintents.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:21)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Ignore the companion object. It was something else I tried that didn't work. Nothing is connected to it. Im taking it out

Comment: what do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: It's solved thank you though @HayssamSoussi. Just make a timer though using intents is all I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**CreateTimer.kt**

```
package com.celadian.goodintents

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.AlarmClock


class CreateTimer: Application() {

    fun startTimer(message: String, seconds: Int, context: Context) {

        val intent = Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER).apply {
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, seconds)
            putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }

        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I tested on my local machine and it triggers alarm without error.

Explanation

on `startTimer`, We got external context as parameter.

because of overseas startActivity invoking, all we have to do are add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag and using context's packageManager object.